# SQL Fetch count of sub query in part select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table BaseVehicle and Version_Main and there is not association between them

I need to fetch the Count of Count(BaseVehicleId), SUM(BaseVehicleID), Count(NewAddedBaseVehicles), Count(DeletedBaseVehicles)

Count, Sum of BaseVehicleID i can get it from the below query,

```
Select  SUM(DISTINCT CAST(BaseVehicleID as BIGINT)), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT BaseVehicleID) 
    from BaseVehicle
```

Count of newly added base vehicles from version date, i'm able to get it from the below query,

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT BaseVehicleId)
from BaseVehicle BV, Version_Main Ver1 
Where Ver.Version_Date IN (Select top 1 Version_Date 
                            from [Version_Main] 
                            order by Version_Date desc) and
BV.InsertDate > Ver.VCDB_Version_Date
```

Count of newly deleted base vehicles from version date, i'm able to get it from the below query,

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT BaseVehicleId)
from BaseVehicle BV, Version_Main Ver
Where Ver.Version_Date IN (Select top 1 Version_Date 
                            from [Version_Main] 
                            order by Version_Date desc) and
BV.InsertDate > Ver.Version_Date and BV.DeleteDate IS NOT NULL
```

My table structure is as follows,

[image]

Can i combine these queries to get the data in one query?

This would be my expected result table

[image]

Comment: Why would you be calculating `SUM(BaseVehicleID)`?  That doesn't make sense.  Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Have updated my question with the expected result table

Answer (score 0):

One of the SQL tricks is to combine [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) with an [aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql).

For example:

```
select 
count(distinct BV.BaseVehicleID) as Count_BaseVehicle,
sum(distinct CAST(BV.BaseVehicleID as BIGINT)) as Sum_BaseVehicle,
count(distinct case when BV.InsertDate > Ver.VersionDate and BV.DeleteDate is null then BV.BaseVehicleID end) as Count_NewBaseVehicle,
count(distinct case when BV.InsertDate > Ver.VersionDate and BV.DeleteDate is not null then BV.BaseVehicleID end) as Count_DeletedBaseVehicle
from BaseVehicle BV
cross join (select max(VersionDate) as VersionDate from Version_Main) Ver;
```

I don't get what the purpose would be for a total sum for an identifier though.